# Hey I have a DataFrame what I want to do is to pick same data and do some calculation?

Tags: python, pandas

This is how my dataframe looks like. Now i want to calculate the average mileage for used and new type. The sample output is like this.

here is my data and i want the dataframe as sample output

```
    Gender  Type    Purchased   Vehicle_Age Mileage MPG
0   Male    Mid-size    Used    15.00   127233  28.7
1   Female  Mid-size    New 1.00    23970   43.4
2   Male    Small   New 7.00    77392   24.0
3   Female  Large SUV   Used    14.00   185397  15.2
4   Female  Small   New 2.00    26001   37.0
5   Female  Minivan New 9.00    180643  20.0
6   Male    Small   Used    6.00    72083   45.7
7   Male    Small   New 11.00   165353  42.0
8   Male    Small   Used    13.00   205288  33.0
9   Female  Small   New 7.00    142897  31.0
10  Male    Minivan Used    14.00   182584  12.0
11  Male    Small SUV   Used    13.00   140479  20.0
12  Female  Small   New 2.00    22114   28.0
13  Female  Mid-size    New 0.25    3454    28.3
14  Female  Large SUV   New 7.00    130905  21.0
15  Female  Small   Used    10.00   105628  35.0
16  Female  Small   New 5.00    48678   30.4
17  Male    Mid-size    New 0.50    6849    40.2
18  Female  Small   Used    10.00   137941  30.0
19  Female  Small SUV   New 4.00    29823   24.9
20  Male    Small SUV   Used    14.00   85763   21.0
21  Female  Small   Used    12.00   134172  31.0
22  Male    Mid-size    Used    12.00   86387   27.0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also post your data and code as plain text rather than as images.

Comment: I have tried pandas.loc to make separate data frame for each type and then calculate the mileage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.pivot_table(index='Type',columns='Purchased',values='Mileage')
```

Comment: Actually I don't understand how your answer is different from @RJAdriaansen 's given 2 hours earlier. Except it is a bit shorter ) You could had at least upvoted his answer.

Comment: this gives me my required ouptut and his answer were hardcoded like mileages were hardcoded

Comment: Take a second look. His answer is _exactly_ the same. Hardcoded was only the initial data which you didn't provide in the question in the proper (copypastable) way.